# Put image istead of radio

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I use an image instead of radio button via Bootstrap or user some other plugins.

Is it possible to style it via css or does Bootstrap do something similar?

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this

[DEMO](http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/391_checkboxes/demo.html)

HTML

```
<p>
<br>
<input id="r1" type="radio" name="rr">
<label for="r1">
<span></span>
Radio Button 1
</label>
</p>
```

CSS

```
input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}


input[type="radio"] + label {
    color: #F2F2F2;
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label span {
    background: url("check_radio_sheet.png") no-repeat scroll -57px top transparent;
}
input[type="radio"] + label span {
    background: url("check_radio_sheet.png") no-repeat scroll -38px top transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 19px;
    margin: -1px 4px 0 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 19px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The prettyCheckable jQuery Plugin replaces the default checkboxes and radio inputs of Bootstrap for better and more attractive ones: 
Check this out: [link](http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/)

> Compatible with IE7+, Chrome, Firefox, Safari and mobile browsers